# Autenticacion de Cuentas de Usuarios Individuales en Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Cuando creo una aplicación Asp.Net Core con Autenticación de Cuentas de Usuarios Individuales  me pide ciertos datos:

1. Nombre de dominio
2. Id de la aplicación
3. Directiva de registro o inicio de sesión

¿Qué debo introducir en ellos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta parte es para configurar (y necesitas estas propiedades que esta solicitando el wizard de proyectos de VS) que es el  [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/active-directory-b2c/) es para centralizar la autenticacion de usuarios (asi los usuarios no se validan contra tu app sino contra el AD B2C) y tu en tu app confias en este servicio
Dale una mirada porque [hasta 50mil usuarios es gratis mira los precios...](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/)

Para eso tendrías que tener una cuenta en Azure, pero [mira esta parte para registrarse free! con un credito inicial de u$s200 mas servicios gratis durante 12 meses](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/free/free-account-faq/) 
Pero lo mas importante... esta parte:

> 50.000 usuarios almacenados al mes y 50.000 autenticaciones al mes con Azure Active Directory B2C esto no caduca a los 12 meses es siempre
>   asi free! esta cantidad

Justo iba a armar un ejemplo de utilización de este servicio, pero hasta que lo tenga disponible te dejo unos enlaces

- [Create an ASP.NET web app with Azure Active Directory B2C sign-up, sign-in, profile edit, and password reset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi)
- [An ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/)
- [Mas ejemplos...](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?service=active-directory-b2c&sort=0)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía